# Optimize SELECT MAX(timestamp) query

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to run this query about once every 5 minutes to be able to run an incremental query to `MERGE` to another table.

```sql
SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM dataset.myTable

-- timestamp is of type TIMESTAMP
```

My concern is that will do a full scan of `myTable` on a regular basis.

What are the best practices for optimizing this query? Will partitioning help even if the `SELECT MAX` doesn't extract the date from the query? Or is it just the columnar nature of BigQuery will make this optimal?

Thank you.

Comment: only `timestamp` column will be scanned - not whole table

Comment: So is there some kind of internal sorting or caching that will make the next SELECT MAX query fast? Max heap?

Comment: you can use partitioning by that column, this will potentially address cost and performance

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, instead of querying your table directly, query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS table within your dataset. Doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#partitions_view).

You can for instance go for:

```
SELECT LAST_MODIFIED_TIME
FROM `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
WHERE TABLE_NAME = "myTable"
```

The PARTITIONS table hold metadata at the rate of one record for each of your partitions. It is therefore greatly smaller than your table and it's an easy way to cut your query costs. (it is also much faster to query).

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately, it doesn't give the same exact result as the previous query.

Comment: Indeed, it depends on the logic you're using to proceed to your merge. The metadata helps you to say "this partition has been updated in the last ten minutes, let's merge it", but doesn't give you the MAX(timestamp).

Comment: For further optimisation of your query, you can indeed use partitioning. That is if you can pinpoint in which partition you expect to find your maximum.